# ioctl sniffer in Linux

Tags: linux, ioctl, sniffing

Is there any utility which allows to sniff ioctl commands and data being sent between application and kernel. I need to track a bug which requires the sequence of ioctl commands send between a working application and non-working application.

Google Search found me a utility for Windows.

```
https://github.com/MartinDrab/IRPMon
```

Is there any such utility in linux

Comment: Try `strace` with a filter

Comment: So, there is no utility as of now which sniff ioctl commands in Linux

Comment: I'm not aware of any tool that would fit your use case directly, but maybe something from [bcc tools collection](https://github.com/iovisor/bcc#examples) could be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the information.. But strace with filter did helped in my debugging..